# WebSocket Safety

Tags: python, web, websocket, chat, tornado

I decided to write a websocket chat that he supported text messaging [unlimited number of characters, not like Twitter :)] and file transfer. 
Ask this question. How to make banal identification data? That is, when the connection is open, the server is just a set of bytes, and even if there is json, it can be easy to substitute: mark as "message" and send confusing file(since the number of characters is not limited, it will sent to all people users). 
That is, briefly, how to discern what comes from the user?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Transfer files via jquery is not accepted, as the websocket is not protected.

UPD
Any wrote that did not understand a question essence. Explain: 1. There is a chat on tornado WS. 2. In chat can send as text messages and files. 3. I control it with javascript BUT if someone will make a connection and send a file for example, as a message? Clients receives a huge number of "unknown byte". The situation is like this - {'msg': 'Hello, world!!1'}; {'file': a file}. All is well, but it would be a shame if {'msg': a file}. It should be clear ;)

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? share with us.

Comment: Hi!  
1. Do not allow users to make multiple connections (looking cookies). But this option is unsafe, get the developer console, and you've established a connection through the console. The format of the data it is easy to fake. 2. About the files had this idea: send messages with a single frame, for files of the same slice. Thus I can distinguish that comes along, BUT see point one, no one is immune to fake a connection. 3. Yes, you can, of course, limit the number of characters, but again, this isn't much help.

Comment: What is your question exactly?   What does this mean: ***"How to make banal identification data?"*** and what does this mean: ***"That is, briefly, how to discern what comes from the user?"***.  FYI, a client can send anything they want to a webSocket.  Your server will have to be prepared to make sure the data it gets is what it was expecting and it is safe before passing it on to other clients.

Comment: Voting to close the question as "Unclear what you're asking" since it is unclear and you have not clarified the question when asked questions.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 , Although you are right, how about we wait a while. It's Sasha's first question. It's obvious that English is not Sasha's native language and it's only been 3 hours since the question was asked and 1 hour since you asked for more data to be supplied - Sasha is probably asleep in a different timezone by now and can't answer you right now... how about we give Sasha a break? We were all green once (I still feel green).

Comment: @Myst - when you post here on StackOverflow, you do NOT post and go to sleep and come back the next day.  Your question will be closed by then if not clear.  You post and you check back several times in the next hour to see if your question is clear.  More than 50% of the opportunities for people to see and answer your question come shortly after you post (that's when most people see it).  If your question is not clear and you are not around to clarify it, then the question is just noise and junk polluting the site.  New users must learn this.

Comment: @Myst - there are a ridiculously high number of poorly written and unclear questions on this site.  It drastically reduces the productivity of this site for everyone, particularly for people who try to spend a lot of time reading, understanding and answering questions (the people who bring a lot of value to the site).  Bad questions are a total productivity killer.   I ask for clarification.  If the OP isn't around, the question gets closed.  You don't post here and come back the next day.  That's hugely unproductive for the way this site works.  It is not like an old forum.

Comment: @jfriend00 - again I know that you are right. On the other hand, Sasha tried answering the first request for clarification about an hour after first posting the question... Not knowing to edit the question, this was done in a comment. I too spend much time on this site and I agree with the issues you raise. But usually I would consider posting a question only after trying a lot of things on my own - so naturally I consider posting the question at the end of my day. Perhaps this discussion should be moved to Meta. We both agree there is a problem. We just approach it differently.

Comment: @Myst - posting at the end of your day and then disappearing is a bad idea.  Post at the middle or beginning of your day when you can be around to engage in the ensuing conversation.  StackOverflow does not work like a typical online forum where you post and come back the next day.  This place is much, much more interactive and there's so much traffic that if your question is in a high traffic tag and isn't seen by someone who understands it and is willing to help in the first hour, chances are it probably won't get an answer.  I'm continuing here for the benefit of the OP when they come back.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I agree. This is a very interactive site and that is why I usually end up not asking anything - I feel it's too late to post a question at the end of the day and that I should do so during the next day... But usually I find a solution in the morning (sleep does that sometimes).  As to Sasha, I hope he or she reads our comments and learns from their mistakes.

Comment: @jfriend00, Myst Thanks for the FAQ on stackoverflow, I will consider the following questions :) Many wrote that did not understand a question essence. Explain: 1. There is a chat on tornado WS. 2. In chat can send as text messages and files. 3. I control it with javascript BUT if someone will make a connection and send a file for example, as a message? Clients receives a huge number of "unknown byte". The situation is like this - {'msg': 'Hello, world!!1'}; {'file': *a file*}. All is well, but it would be a shame if {'msg': *a file*}. It should be clear ;)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

Before I answer your question, allow me to clarify a few points about this site and our community. This is your first question, so maybe you didn't know:

1. SO (StackOverflow) is not a forum, it's more like both a chat and a library. If you ask a question, you are expected to stay on line for at least an hour or two to check in and give more information if somebody asks you.

   If somebody asks for more information, edit the question - don't answer inside the comments (you can add a comment saying that you updated the question, but the question should be edited).

   If you are not here to clarify your question, it WILL be closed because there are many people wanting answers and we give priority to the people who are here to respond.
2. It is important that your questions include information about what you already tried. It is better if your questions include some of the code you wrote when you tried your own solution.

   Otherwise, it feels like you are trying to outsource your work to the community - which is a very big No No.
3. It is important that your questions are clear and that you write in the best English that you can manage.

Please read the comments to see what I mean about the community's expectations.

---

**As for Websocket security**:

I do not know what language you work with, so I will write in [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) because it's easier for me and I think the code will be easier to read.

Websockets start as an HTTP connection which is then "upgraded" to a websocket connection.

Since most applications already have HTTP security / authentication logic that they wrote for the website, it is best to use this same security / authentication logic for websockets.

This is usually done BEFORE the connection is upgraded.

It is true that sometimes people write a new security / authentication logic layer for websockets, but that is not the most effective way to deal with this issue (mainly because messages could be sent to the websocket while authentication is still being processed, which starts a new world of issues and considerations).

Here is an example, using the [Plezi framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi), that requires authentication before the upgrade. test this example by installing the plezi gem (terminal: `$  [sudo] gem install plezi`) and running the following code in irb (terminal : `$ irb`):

```
require 'plezi'

class WebsocketSecDemo
    # pre_connect is called before the upgrade, while still in HTTP mode.
    def pre_connect
        # return false (refuse the connection) unless the auth logic is okay
        return false unless auth_logic
        true
    end

    def on_message data
        puts "got #{data}"
        response << data
        broadcast :ws_write, data
    end

    def index
        "Check this using http://www.websocket.org/echo.html
        \r\nConnect to the websocket at ws://localhost:3000/
        \r\nTo authenticate, visit http://localhost:3000/login
        \r\nTo un-authenticate visit http://localhost:3000/logout"
    end
    def login
        cookies[:my_auth] = true
        redirect_to :index
    end
    def logout
        cookies[:my_auth] = nil
        redirect_to :index
    end

    # protected methods aren't available to the HTTP router.
    protected

    def ws_write data
        response << data
    end

    # The worst auth logic in the history of man kind...
    def auth_logic
        cookies[:my_auth] == true
    end
end

Plezi.listen
Plezi.route '/', WebsocketSecDemo

# exit the terminal to start the demo
exit
```

Now visit:

- [localhost:3000 - for instructions](http://localhost:3000/)
- [localhost:3000/login - to authenticate](http://localhost:3000/login)
- [localhost:3000/logout - to remove authentication](http://localhost:3000/logout)

Also use [www.websocket.org/echo.html](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) a few times to try and connect to the websocket at ws://localhost:3000/ - try this:

1. before authentication;
2. after authentication (login); and
3. after you 'logout'...

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! According to the recommendations in the comments, I've updated my question with details. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908504/websocket-safety/31910414#comment51743930_31908504

Comment: @Sasha, thank you for giving more details. Can you click on the `edit` link under your question's tag list and insert the extra information into the question? - This will help other people that didn't read the comments to help you. Also, you can update the tags to add Tornado and Python.

Comment: Done! Changed question and added tags)